# PHP script runs much longer than max_execution_time?

Tags: php, timeout, execution-time

PHP is running as an Apache module.

The script start with a: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`

What it does is basically connecting to a database, doing a big `SELECT`query and looping through the results, writing them to a file and echoing a "result ok" after each write with explicit `flush();`

There is no `sleep()` call.

This is a "test" script made from a co-worker of mine for backup purposes and is intended to run up to a few hours! I thought I was aware of script execution time limit and thought his script would time out after 300 seconds...
But it didn't !

It's invoked from a web browser. The page is left open and we can see the results being echoed in real-time.

Why doesn't it time out?
Even stranger, one of the test issued a "**Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded**" but this appeared at least after 2 hours of execution!

What's going on here? Is there something to understand between max_execution_time and flush() or a browser window being kept opened?

Comment: ini_get('max_execution_time') what's result?

Comment: echo ini_get('max_execution_time'); // says 300

Comment: Try to increase in php.ini & restart apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that may cause this is if PHP is running in safe mode. ini_get('max_execution_time') should tell you if it's actually being set.

Edit: Spotted your comment above.

> echo ini_get('max_execution_time'); // says 300

If 300 is reported, and your not on Windows, @mishu is likely right. Your SELECT query is probably taking hours.

Answer (score 10):

As you can see on the man page for the set_time_limit function, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#refsect1-function.set-time-limit-notes) the total execution time you are setting only affects the actual script. The time spent on database queries or any other external calls is not counted *(if the OS is not Windows)*.

Comment: I think you and @GOPalmer are right, I thought I read somewhere database queries were taken into account for max execution time but they are not. We do have queries that run for ages. Thanks